# PayPal Advanced maximum length of user-defined fields

Tags: paypal

I'm using PayPal Advanced, and am using the user-defined fields USER1 - USER10 to send some data with the transaction that will help me identify it when it comes back through the Silent Post request. Does anyone know what the maximum length that is allowed for the value of these USERx fields? The documents do not specify one that I can find.

Here is the relevant section of the dev guide discussing these fields (from [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#passing-other-data-to-your-server-using-post-or-silent-post)):

> **Passing Other Data to Your Server Using Post or Silent Post**
>
> The USER1 through USER10 Payflow parameters are ten optional string type
>   parameters intended to store your temporary data, such as variables,
>   session IDs, order numbers, and so on. These parameters enable you to
>   pass internal information to your server using the Post or Silent Post
>   feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is limit of **255 characters** for these fields . You can check this on the page 54 of the below document :

https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowlink_guide.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I must have been looking in the wrong doc and missed that.